# Irreducible unitary representation of compact group is contained in the left-regular representation

Tags: representation-theory, topological-groups

Given a compact metric topological group $G$ and an irreducible unitary representation $\pi$ of $G$, I would like to show that $\pi$ is contained in the left-regular representation $\lambda$ of $G$.

One of my reference books is 'A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis' by Folland. In chapter 5. the Peter-Weyl Theorem is exposed. However, I content myself with the weaker statement above. I was hoping that you could explain how to prove the result above (maybe by using matrix coefficients or otherwise).
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u$ be any  representation of the compact group $G$  on the Hilbert space $H$.

Fixing a unit vector $\xi $ in $H$,  define the linear map
$$
  F:H\to L^2(G),
  $$
by
$$
  F(\eta )|_g = \langle \eta , u_g(\xi )\rangle,  \quad\forall \eta\in H, \quad\forall g\in G.
  $$
For  $h$ in $G$, notice that
$$
  \lambda _h(F(\eta ))|_g =
  F(\eta )|_{h^{-1}g} =
  \langle \eta , u_{h^{-1}g}(\xi )\rangle  = $$$$ =
  \langle u_h(\eta ), u_g(\xi )\rangle  =
  F(u_h(\eta ))|_g,
  $$
so we see that
$$
  \lambda _h\circ F=  F\circ u_h,
  \tag 1
  $$
meaning that $F$ is a covariant map.

Assuming from now on that $u$ is irreducible, notice that (1) implies that $F^*F$ commutes with $u$, so the Schur Lemma
implies that $F=cI$, for some constant $c$.  Defining $V=c^{-1/2}F$, we have that $V$ is an isometric operator  and clearly
$\lambda _h\circ V=  V\circ u_h$.

The conclusion is that $V$ establishes a unitary  equivalence between $u$ and the restriction of $\lambda $ to the range of $V$.

Comment: Thank you Ruy for this rapid reply and good explanation. I fully understood the proof.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it!